# find out and print decimal values in an file

Tags: regex, perl

I want to display all the decimal number in a file

MY CODE

```
my $input = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $input) or die $!;  
my @lines = <FILE>;
foreach(@lines){
  $line++;
  if($_ =~ '\d+'){
  print "magic number found in line number".$line."\n";
  }

     }
 close(FILE1);
```

OUTPUT I GET

```
magic number found in line number 30
```

OUTPUT I NEED

```
magic number 10 found in line number 30.
```

How do I display the decimal value also.

ALSO I NEED TO PRINT HEXADECIMAL AND OCTALS NUMBERS.
using [0-9a-fA-F.]+ regex for hexadecimal is giving me random outputs

Comment: a decimal value as in `10.5609`

Comment: yes. integer and float both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to open your file explicitly or to read it into an array. This program will do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  print "magic number $1 found in line number $.\n" if /(\d[\d.]*)/;
}
```

Comment: could you tell me regex command to search for hexadecimal and octal numbers. using [0-9a-fA-F.]+ for hexadecimal gives me random answers

Comment: There is obviously no way for a regex to distinguish, for instance, the hex number `A` from the word `A`. But you may get some mileage from surrounding the pattern in word boundary anchors `\b` which will make sure that the string isn't preceded or succeeded by alphanumeric characters. Try `/\b([[:xdigit:]]+)\b/` or `/\b([0-7]+)\b/` for octal.

Comment: okay But i guess if hexadecimal starts with 0x then we can filter it by using /0x[0-9a-fA-F.]+/ . But i am getting error in printing the value, line number is printing fine

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
egrep -won '0x[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]*|[0-9][0-9]*'
```

(w: word boundary. o: print ONLY the match, not the whole line. n: also add the line number)

will print:

```
line:value
```

(and also works if there are multiple values on the same line! it will then display as many "line:value" as there was a match)

On your own code extract it shows:

```
1:0
```

(ie, in line 1, we see a "0")

Comment: Sorry didn't mention it clearly, i am running perl script on a .C file and right now decimals/octals works fine. I am having problem in printing hexadecimals like "0x5A3"

Comment: oops, sorry, I messed up the 0x regexp: i fix it now.